# Angular package using its own service inside component

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular5, angular-library

I'm creating an angular library for components shared across multiple apps.  I'm running into trouble when using a service from inside the library inside a component from the library.

The service is intended to be injected at the root of the app (not library) and can be used throughout the app.

In this scenario, we're looking at the `ToastService` and `UIToastComponent`. The `UIToastComponent` is exported from the `UIToastModule`.

The app then imports the `UIToastModule` inside the application's `AppModule`, where is also provides the `ToastService`.

The `<ui-toast></ui-toast>` tag sits in the application's `app.component.html` file.

The idea being, in any component inside the application, the developer can inject `ToastService` and call `this.toastService.success('Great Success!')`, which is picked up by the `UIToastComponent` and displays the toast.

The `constructor` for the `UIToastComponent` can't seem to pick up the service, and at runtime I the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ToastService is not defined
at UIToastComponent.ctorParameters (ngx-example-library.js:197)
at ReflectionCapabilities._ownParameters (core.js:2060)
at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (core.js:2095)
at JitReflector.parameters (platform-browser-dynamic.js:61)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15635)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15527)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata 
(compiler.js:15012)
at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14866)
at eval (compiler.js:34392)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

The import statement for the `ToastService` inside the `UIToastComponent` looks like this:

```
import { ToastService } from '../../services/toast.service';
```

The library follows the [Angular Package Format v5](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview) and was originally based on https://github.com/juristr/ngx-tabs-libdemo

Here's the sourcecode for the library:  [ngx-example-library](https://github.com/stevedeighton/ngx-example-library)

**EDIT**

I've implemented `forRoot()` as per Günter Zöchbauer's suggestion but unfortunately still I get the same result, its likely I've implemented it incorrectly...

Here's what the newly created `UICoreModule` looks like inside the library:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { UIToastComponent } from './components/toast/toast.component';
import { ToastService } from './services/toast.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        UIToastComponent,
    ],
    providers: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        UIToastComponent,
    ]
})

export class UICoreModule {

    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {ngModule: UICoreModule, providers: [ToastService]};
    }

}
```

And here's the `AppModule` inside the application:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {UICoreModule} from 'ngx-example-library';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UICoreModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Appreciate the help with this one, it's a real mind-boggler this one. Bet it's really easy - when you know how!

**EDIT (2)**

The solution mentioned above **does** work in AOT mode, but not JIT mode. Happy to live with that for now, the app builds AOT anyway. Development may become when app grows though.

Comment: Post all the relevant code: service, component, module definitions.

Comment: Hey @JBNizet, thanks for offering to help.  I have updated the library repo, link above. Also I've published it to npm `ngx-example-library`. Unfortunately i'm not in a position to share the application but, I've added an edit that shows the `AppModule` above. Hope you can help! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `forRoot` in the module that defines your package, provide the service there and import the module in `AppModule` with `MyModule.forRoot()`

See also https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method

Comment: Hey @günter-zöchbauer, thanks the help. I was sure this would do it! I've implemented it but I'm getting the same result. If you wouldn't mind taking a peek I'd appreciate it. I've made edits above and updated the repo. Also published to npm `ngx-example-library`. Thanks!

Comment: Where and how do you inject it. Please add that code as well. How does the service and it's constructor look like?

Comment: It's injected inside the [UIToastComponent](https://github.com/stevedeighton/ngx-example-library/blob/master/src/ui-core/components/toast/toast.component.ts), which also resides in the library. Sorry, here's the [ToastService](https://github.com/stevedeighton/ngx-example-library/blob/master/src/ui-core/services/toast.service.ts)

Comment: Actually this looks good. Don't know why it still doesn't work

Comment: Interestingly, I've just discovered that it works in AOT mode (I'm using CLI) but not in JIT mode. I can probably live with that!